# python: test whether subprocess call throws an expected exception

Tags: python, unit-testing, exception, subprocess

I'm trying to test calling an external command with no arguments will throw a CalledProcessError exception using python2.7's unittest module like this:

```
import unittest

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase)
    def testCommand(self):
        cmd = 'MyCommand'
        gotLog = 'UndefinedGot'
        with self.assertRaises(CalledProcessError) as context:
            gotLog = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT).strip()
        expectedLog = 'some error'
        self.assertEqual(context.exception.message, expectedLog)
```

However, running the test still gives me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "MyTest.py", line 51, in testCommand
   gotLog = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT).strip()
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 544, in check_output:
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
CalledProcessError: Command 'MyCommand' returned non-zero exit status 2
```

Is it that the unittest's exception test cannot handle external commands, e.g., the exception got intercepted elsewhere?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only think that the `CalledProcessError` name has been trampled, maybe explicitly stating it would help

```
with self.assertRaises(subprocess.CalledProcessError) as context:
```

Comment: Thank you! Wish the error message could've been a bit more intuitive.